# Error while executing sample todomvc Sightly app

Tags: aem, sightly, todomvc

I am trying to execute [todomvc](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sightly-sample-todomvc) sample Sightly app. After creating a package and installing it on AEM, when I try to view the Todo page (created by package) by navigating to

```
http://localhost:4502/content/todo.html
```

It shows up as blank page. When I checked the error log, I found following exception:

> GET /content/todo.html HTTP/1.1]
> com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter Error during include
> of SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/content/todo/jcr:content',
> selectorString='null', extension='html', suffix='null'
>
> org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Cannot get DefaultSlingScript: No
> use provider could resolve identifier:
> libs.granite.sightly.templates.ClientLibUseObject

Kindly guide me what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have runtime errors during libs.granite.sightly.templates.ClientLibUseObject  method execution 
or 
check if the corresponding bundle (with that class) is in 'Resolved' state (the most likely cause).

Comment: The most probable reason could be that the bundle might be in any state except Active. Some of the dependencies might not have been resolved. Expand the bundle to check for missing dependencies.